# get the Requested URL of the Client in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

in order to validate the caller in WCF service, I need to know the requester domain. How can I get the domain like 'http//:abd.web.com'?

Note: I can get the IP using `IncomingMessageProperties` but I need the domain because the IP not static

thanks

Comment: There is no domain involved if it's a server to server call. You should think of some other way of validating the client such as secret or token sent via header.

Comment: I'm with @ChetanRanpariya: what if I call the WCF service from a desktop application?

Comment: i have a list of authorized Link. I just need to prevent anyone else to call the service

Comment: There is no way you can figure out if wcf service is being called from web application, or desktop application or even from another wcf service until the client tells that by some or the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to invent something that is already available for you: use certificates between your service (and trusted parties):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2012/07/03/a-solution-to-limit-specified-client-certificates-to-consume-wcf-service/

WCF provides many different ways to secure communication.